# Selenium RC and php test case

Tags: selenium-rc

I have installed Selenium RD successfully and i can generate php test case with selenium IDE, but when i run the test case after starting selenium RC server, it open Firefox browser and after that in the command line interface it shows that the selenium RC server is not found. i cant figure out the problem. Can any one tell me the full procedure to set up Selenium RC, Pear, and then how can i run a php test case and generate a result. the example with screen shot will be very helpful..

pls help me as early as possible

Answer (score 1):

Plz check set browser URL and open command in the test case. 
In test case open command should be such that it appends the browser URL and combining both should open URL.

When running test case also verify that the whether the required Web page is loading or not.